# How to parse data inside CDATA in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a column in the table with type `CLOB` and it stores the payloads.

I need to get the value with respect to `tenantId` (7 in this case). How do write a query to get the same. Can't use `substr` or `instr` since the order of `tenantId` changes from record to record.

```
<PayLoad><![CDATA[{"order":{"entityErrors":[],"action":"CONFIRM","tenantId":"7","Id":"2","deliveryReservationDetails":[{"reservationId":"c05e0c77-1c8f-4dce-a388-fe97fd36f96e","fulfillmentLocationType":"Store"}]}}]]></PayLoad>
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I don't know where is this stored procedure , I just need to parse the content  of the coulmn to get the tenantId .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 12 you should be able to do:

```
SELECT tenantId
FROM   your_table t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/PayLoad/.'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.your_xml_column )
         COLUMNS cdata CLOB PATH '.'
       ) x
       ON ( 1 = 1 )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         x.cdata,
         '$'
         COLUMNS ( tenantId VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.order.tenantId' )
       ) j
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

(Untested as I'm on 11g for the next few hours)

On Oracle 11:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( x.cdata, '"tenantId":"((\\"|[^"])*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS tenantId
FROM   your_table t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/PayLoad/.'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.your_xml_column )
         COLUMNS cdata CLOB PATH '.'
       ) x
       ON ( 1 = 1 )
```

Or (if the JSON string will not occur in another branch of the XML) you could just use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_xml_column,
         '"tenantId":"((\\"|[^"])*)"',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS tenantId
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CDATA payload appears to be JSON, so if you're on 12c and only have one order per CDATA you can do:

```
select json_value(x.cdata, '$.order.tenantId' returning number) as tenantid
from your_table t
cross join xmltable('/PayLoad'
  passing xmltype(your_clob)
  columns cdata clob path './text()'
) x;
```

As @MTO pointed out, treating the JSON value as a number may not be valid, as it's shown as a string in the raw JSON. Making it `returning varchar2(10)` or some other suitable size may be more appropriate (and safer, at least until you use it).

Quick demo with your XML as a CTE:

```
with your_table (your_clob) as (
  select to_clob('<PayLoad><![CDATA[{"order":{"entityErrors":[],"action":"CONFIRM","tenantId":"7","Id":"2","deliveryReservationDetails":[{"reservationId":"c05e0c77-1c8f-4dce-a388-fe97fd36f96e","fulfillmentLocationType":"Store"}]}}]]></PayLoad>') from dual
)
select json_value(x.cdata, '$.order.tenantId' returning number) as tenantid
from your_table t
cross join xmltable('/PayLoad'
  passing xmltype(your_clob)
  columns cdata clob path './text()'
) x;

TENANTID               
---------------------- 
7
```

Comment: Not relevant to the SQL part of the answer but although `tenantId` is in this instance `7` it is being stored as a string `"7"` so converting to a number may not be correct.

Comment: select json_value(x.cdata, '$.order.tenantId' returning varchar2(10)) as tenantid
from TRANSACTION_1.YFS_REPROCESS_ERROR t
cross join xmltable('/PayLoad'
  passing xmltype(MESSAGE)
  columns cdata clob path './text()'
) x where ERRORTXNID='2017040915433240696011'; This is the query I am using..where MESSAGE is the column name that stores cdata , but shows ORA-00907 error. Please help

Comment: @NagarajB - so, you're on 11g or earlier then, not 12c? Either of MTO's 11g answers should work for you in that case. (You might want to consider [accepting that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helps you; you can do the same for some of your older questions too).